# Calling properties of a class declared as List<my class> in C#

Tags: c#, class, properties, listbox

I have the following classes:

```
  public class Weather
  {
      public int id { get; set; }
      public string main { get; set; }
      public string description { get; set; }
  }

  public class RootObject
  {
      public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
  }
```

I am trying to get the properties of class Weather in variables, I've written the code as:

```
   void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
          var root1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
          this.DataContext = root1;

          string skycondition = root1.weather.main.ToString();
    }
```

Although the properties "main", "description", and "id" are binded in the xaml in a ListBox and they are working fine, but I've to display some images on the basis of these values that's why i need to get them in variables.

NOTE: I've to retrieve these values when the main page is loaded, not on the Selection change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
weather is the List<Weather> object .. not the Weather object.
```

So, `weather.main` won't work. May be something like `weather[0].main` is what you want.